# Spark Sql Dataset get index number

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a case class like this:

```
Person(name:String = null, rank:Integer = null)
```

And I have a `dataset: Dataset[Person]`

Let's say the dataset has 5 person objects:

```
Dataset[  Person(name = "Jack",id = 100, rank = null), 
          Person(name = "Mary",id = 400, rank = null),
          Person(name = "Tom",id = 199, rank = null), 
          Person(name = "Linda", id = 55, rank = null),
          Person(name = "Wendy", id = 30, rank = null)]
```

I want to populate the rank field in Scala, after sorting the dataset by id. So that the dataset becomes:

```
Dataset[  Person(name = "Wendy", id = 30, rank = 1), 
          Person(name = "Linda", id = 55, rank = 2),
          Person(name = "Jack", id = 100, rank = 3), 
          Person(name = "Tom", id = 199, rank = 4),
          Person(name = "Mary", id = 400, rank = 5)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what are the rules for ranking? Can you order the dataset somehow? Otherwise this does not make much sense in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @RaphaelRoth Thanks for the feedback. Yes, it would be order by a field, let's say order by Person.Id field.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataset then, you can add rank column using [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function

```
ds.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"id")))
```

Or also with the rank function

```
ds.withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.orderBy("id")))
```

> def row_number(): Column
>
> Window function: returns a sequential number starting at 1 within a
>   window partition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But this will transform the dataset into a data frame tho? I want the rank to be in inside the person object

Comment: Actually this works! I just need to convert the Dataframe to Dataset[Person]. Super!

Comment: Yeah It gives dataframe and you need to convert to Dataset[Person]. If this answers then you can accept as an answer.